# How to convert a language code to language name

Tags: javascript

Are there any function for converting a language code to language name? For example;

'en' to English,
'ru' to Russian,
'tr' to Turkish

If you help me i will be glad.

Comment: You could just extract the relevant part of the table from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Comment: see also https://www.npmjs.com/package/iso-639-1

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks. I gave feedback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this using `Intl`:

```js
const getLanguage = (code) => {
    const lang = new Intl.DisplayNames(['en'], {type: 'language'});
    return lang.of(code);
}

const russianLang = getLanguage("ru"); // Russian
console.log(russianLang);
```

You could write a function that receives a code and then use `Intl.DisplayNames` to get the according language.

Read more about `Intl` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DisplayNames/DisplayNames).

You could rewrite the function in 1 line if you like:

```js
const getL = (c) => new Intl.DisplayNames(['en'], {type: 'language'}).of(c);
console.log(getL("ru"));
```